# asp.net codebehind find webmethods

Tags: asp.net

In the code behind for each page, how can I use reflection to get all the webmethods I have defined on that page?

Currently I have the following and call it in the Page_Load() but it doesn't find my 1 static function that I have a webmethod attribute on.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = this.GetType().GetMethods();
foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
{
    foreach (Attribute attribute in method.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        if (attribute is WebMethodAttribute)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That comes back with nothing at all. I'm sure it has something to do with the object I'm looking at. It doesn't look like the static methods are really part of the partial code behind class or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for Public static :

```
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public Default()
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(Default).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                      BindingFlags.Static);
            foreach (MethodInfo method in methodInfos)
            {
                foreach (Attribute attribute in method.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                {
                    if (attribute is WebMethodAttribute)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static void A() 
        { 
        }
    }
```

Works for me

Comment: That worked. Seems the typeof(Default) was the missing link. I thought 'this' would refer to that but I guess not. Thank you!